# ASCII values not appearing in mailer but appearing in local machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, character-encoding, ascii

I want to use a En-dash with ASCII value &#8211. I am using haml and did the coding as

```
do this
= "&#8211".html_safe
task
```

so as to appear as "do this -- task". In the place of double dash I need an EN-dash. The above code is working fine in my local machine. when I am sending a mail with the above text to the recipent, he is seeing it as `do this &#8211 task`.

Can anyone help  me in how to make it appear as the En-dash in the mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASCII character codes utilize concluding semicolons (`;`) to delimit characters for interpolation. Add a concluding semicolon to your en-dash ASCII code:

```
= "&#8211;".html_safe
```

Comment: Yeah this worked. Thanks @Zeantsoi on finding and telling the importance on concluding semicolon.

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider upvoting this answer if you have found it particularly helpful in your understanding.